# jcarousel not working in Google Chrome

Tags: magento, google-chrome, jcarousel

I am having a problem with the jcarousel in my Magento webshop. I bought a templete for my webshop so that I did not have to do any programming myself since I don't have any knowledge about programming.

On the bottom of the product pages of my webshop a jcarousel is shown in which related products are shown. This function works well in every browser except Google Chrome. Here none of the products in the carousel can be seen.

Someone on an other forum told me it had to do with the width of the carousel. That this particular line was causing the trouble:

Since I have no knowledge whatsoever on programming, I don't know how to adjust the width. Can any of you tell me if this is indeed the problem and how I can solve it?

To give you an idea what it is all about, here's an url of a page on which it doesn't work:
http://supplementendeal.nl/index.php/creatine/scitec-crea-bomb.html

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that a width of 179769313486231600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000px

is being inserted into the li tag of the unordered list. Without the actual javascript its hard to say how to fix this.